# MPI: Distributing segments of large file does not speedup execution

Tags: c, mpi

I have a large bioinformatics file (fasta), and I am using MPI to open the file at specific regions depending on the current program's ID. Then, I transcribe the amino acid sequence into their corresponding proteins.

```
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  MPI_File in;
  int id;
  int p;
  long buffersize = 3000000000/p;
  MPI_Offset fileStart = buffersize * id;
  char* nucleotides = (char*)malloc(buffersize);
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
  MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, argv[1], MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &in);
  MPI_File_read_at(in, fileStart, nucleotides, buffersize, MPI_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  /* Calculations */
  /* Write result */
  MPI_File_close(&in);
  free(nucleotides);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

I expect a speedup correlated with number of machines running the algorithm. However, I observe running my applications across multiple machines does not change execution time. Execution time appears to be independent of number of machines listed in my hostfile.

Any ideas how to get the expected behavior of more machines decreasing the read time?

Comment: too many variables (`p` and `id` for example) are used unitialized

Comment: First, you have to make sure you are running on a scalable filesystem. For example, if a NFS server is the bottleneck, performance might not increase as you expect when adding more nodes. If running on Lustre, make sure your input file is stripped on enough OST. Last but not least, use collective I/O (e.g. `MPI_File_real_all_at()`) instead.

Comment: Okay. Wedon't have much time to troubleshoot if it's our lab's NFS system which is the bottleneck. I do not think we're running on Lustre. We will look into using MPI_file_read_all_at().

Comment: start by making sure you are using initialized variables :-)

Comment: What should we initialize them to if we are getting the value from MPI_Comm_rank/size()?

Comment: do not use them **before** you initialize them. I encourage you to compile with `-Wall` to spot this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

To turn the comments into an answer:
Turn this

```
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  MPI_File in;
  int id;
  int p;
  //you are using p uninitialized here!!!
  long buffersize = 3000000000/p;
  //same applies to id
  MPI_Offset fileStart = buffersize * id;
  char* nucleotides = (char*)malloc(buffersize);
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
  MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, argv[1], MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &in);
  MPI_File_read_at(in, fileStart, nucleotides, buffersize, MPI_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  /* Calculations */
  /* Write result */
  MPI_File_close(&in);
  free(nucleotides);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

into this:

```
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  MPI_File in;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int id;
  int p;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
  long buffersize = 3000000000/p;
  MPI_Offset fileStart = buffersize * id;
  char* nucleotides = (char*)malloc(buffersize);
  MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, argv[1], MPI_MODE_RDONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &in);
  MPI_File_read_at(in, fileStart, nucleotides, buffersize, MPI_CHAR, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  /* Calculations */
  /* Write result */
  MPI_File_close(&in);
  free(nucleotides);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

No guarantee about whether the rest will work above.
I would highly recommend to make yourself comfortable with C programming before starting to write MPI code because you might end up lost. MPI issues are difficult to debug.